# Laravel Amazon S3 - downloads one file only: I want all files downloaded

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, download

I have a script I run from a Laravel web route and although all file names are in an array from the S3 directory, looping through the array only downloads the first image. For some reason the remaining files are not downloaded or simply ignored.

No errors are logged and removing the return on the response makes no difference either. I've fiddled around with the headers without success. Any suggestions as to what is preventing all the images from being downloaded would be appreciated greatly.

I've spent several hours on this problem having already looked at many SO questions and answers, and nothing has helped.

Here is the script within the web route.

```
set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

    $files = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('original');

    foreach($files as $file) 
    {
        $tmp=explode('/', $file);
        $path=Storage::disk('s3')->url($file);

        $headers = [
            'Content-Type'                  =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Description'           =>  'File Transfer',
            'Content-Disposition'           =>  'attachment; filename='.$tmp[1],
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding'     =>  'binary',
            'Connection'                    =>  'Keep-Alive',
            'Expires'                       =>  '0',
            'Cache-Control'                 =>  'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Pragma'                        =>  'public',
            'filename'                      =>  $tmp[1],
            'Content-Length'                =>  strlen(file_get_contents($path)),
        ];

        return response()->make(file_get_contents($path), 200, $headers);
    }

    set_time_limit(60);
```

The filenames are (for example) `original/1839493833.jpg` and I explode each to just get the filename without the S3 directory name.

Comment: `return` stops further execution of the function. Doing it in a `foreach` will not accomplish what you hope. You'll need to have your server fetch the files and combine them into a zip file or something.

Comment: Ah, okay. So the only choice is to compress all together. But I have another script which downloads each file to the local storage without any problems. Strange.

Comment: Not strange; a `foreach` will work fine for that, but not if you `return` within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download multiple files from one HTTP request. And even if you could, the `return` statement inside your `foreach` loop exits the function as soon as the first file is downloaded. This has nothing to do with S3.

Either, download the files one by one sending multiple requests, or you can download them all, add them to a ZIP file using [`ZipArchive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) and then return the archive as the response.

Feel free to take a look at the PHP example from the official docs called [*Example #1 Create a Zip archive*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).